# Working with BigInteger bypassing Integer.toString()

Tags: java, biginteger

I want to get a remainder of a fourth power of a number. Here is my code:

```
static int testMod(int a, int mod) {

/*  //This looks clear
    BigInteger a4 = a;    
    return (a4.pow(4))%mod;
*/

    //This works
    String a2String = Integer.toString(a);
    String mod2String = Integer.toString(mod);
    BigInteger a4 = new BigInteger(a2String);
    BigInteger modBigInt = new BigInteger(mod2String);
    a4 = a4.pow(4);

    return a4.remainder(modBigInt).intValue();
}
```

It works fine, but the conversion to String seems unnecessary, and using the `%` operator would be more concise than `a.remainder(b)`. Is it possible to rewrite it to make it more clear?

Comment: Should be "fourth" or "4th" power.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf-long-

Comment: Since a4 could be larger than a long, you would potentially lose precision and return the wrong answer if you convert a4 to an int to perform the modulus operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get rid of the conversions through `String` by using `BigInteger.valueOf(long)` to convert your `int`s to `BigInteger`.  You cannot apply the `%` operator to `BigInteger` operands, however.  If you could, then `BigInteger.remainder()` would not exist.  On the other hand, as @LouisWasserman observes, there is `BigInteger.modPow()` to perform the exponentiation and remainder in one call.

Additionally, `BigInteger` supports method chaining, as you recognize.  You could do the whole thing in one statement if you wanted, but I think this is a good compromise between concision and readability:

```
static int testMod(int a, int mod) {
    BigInteger bigA = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
    BigInteger bigMod = BigInteger.valueOf(mod);

    return bigA.modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(4), bigMod).intValue();
}
```

Comment: Why not use `BigInteger.modPow`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, indeed why not?  I have no good response.  Updated.

Comment: Hmm.  I think you might actually have to do `bigA.modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(4), bigMod)`, which is a shame, but I suspect still worth it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, yes, you're right.  It's not as pretty, but one `modPow()` is much better than chaining `pow()` and `remainder()`.

Comment: FWIW: Actually, `remainder()` could still exist, even if there were operator overloading. My (Delphi) BigInteger implementation has operator overloading as well as full function names.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, of course it *could* exist.  I said it *would not* exist.  Of course that is a speculative, unprovable assertion, but I am nevertheless confident about it.

Comment: Yes, it would exist, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is any better or not, but it gets rid of the unnecessary conversion to `String` and back:

```
static int testMod(int a, int mod)
{
    BigInteger a4 = BigInteger.valueOf(a).pow(4);

    return a4.remainder(BigInteger.valueOf(mod)).intValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has not been proposed but you may also think of using the `import static` to lighten up your code and also the method `BigInteger#mod` instead of `#remainder`

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import static java.math.BigInteger.valueOf;


public class BigInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(testMod(5,36)); // 13
        System.out.println(testMod(250, 999)); // 160
    }

    public static int testMod(int a, int mod) {
        return valueOf(a).pow(4).mod(valueOf(mod)).intValue();
    }
}
```